# Artisan skipping migrations

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan, laravel-migrations

So, I've just pulled down a project in Laravel 5 from Github that I've done no work on before, but I need to set up to add a feature or three.

Problem is, I don't have any of the database tables for this project. That should be easy enough to fix, as the migrations are all there in the proper folder.

I run `php artisan migrate` and it tells me that there's a problem with one of the migrations trying to update a table that doesn't exist.

The problem is, that isn't the first migration by date. And an earlier migration should create the table it's saying isn't there yet.

Basically, it's something like this:

```
Migration 1
Migration 2
Migration 3
Migration 4
Migration 5 <--- here's where the error is occurring
Migration 6
etc....
```

It doesn't appear to be running migrations before the migration that throws an error at all, and it's not writing anything to the migrations table in that schema.

The error(s) I'm getting is:

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'table1' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `table1` where `code` = DEFAULT_ADDRESS limit 1)
```

and

```
[PDOException]
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'table1' doesn't exist
```

Needless to say, I'm a bit confused as to why it would skip migrations, even ones that don't concern that table.

Comment: You should have a "migrations" table in your database, which store all done migrations. Take a look!

Comment: I do. It's not writing anything to it. It's not even writing anything to the migrations table in another schema (I checked that too.)

Answer (score 1):

You should run:

```
php artisan migrate:status
```

It should show you migrations in the order they should be run. Make sure the order is valid. If it's not probably something was messed up it you might need to alter files to have valid order of your migrations.

Comment: Strange. It doesn't. It merely gives me the same error messages as above. `[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]` and `[PDOException]`.

Comment: So it's quite possible the problem is somewhere else. When you run for example `php artisan route:list` is everything working fine? The problem might be in some service providers or some constructors

Comment: Same exact errors. 

I'm wondering now if I missed something and didn't notice I missed it when I did the composer install.

Comment: So it seems the problem is not in migrations. You might be running for example some queries in controller constructors and it might be a problem but it's hard to say without whole code and this is probably not for SO to investigate this.